# Solidify vertex group, make it thinner and thicker one some part of the mesh. Model included!

Tags: modeling, modifiers, vertex-groups, solidify-modifier

I'm modeling a PET bottle, and my idea was to make the plastic thicker at the bottle's neck and bottom while leaving the middle thinner, using the Solidify modifier.

I thought of creating two vertex groups, one for the neck and bottom of the bottle, and one for the middle, then using the vertex groups in the Solidify modifier. However, I can't seem to get it to work. I've uploaded the model here and hope someone can help me out!

EDIT:

Im trying to recreate yours but I get this:

[image]

And my solidify doesnt work in the middle part

[image]

EDIT 2:

Ah ok! I used the wrong vertex group! Problem solved

Comment: Here is the model: https://blend-exchange.com/b/Dm61KgqM/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control thickness using one vertex group:

[image]

And one modifier:

[image]

So that in red areas thickness will be 0.2, and in green 0.1 (50%)

You can define weight when assign vertices to vertex group:

[image]

Comment: wow! Thats great! Hehe, how did you do it?

Comment: You can define weight when assign vertices to vertex group.

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/1PQwp3l9/